# How create multiples fnRender in my datatable

Tags: jquery, servlets, datatables

```
"aoColumnDefs": [ {
     "fnRender": function (o) {
         return '<_a href="Servlet?action=edit&id=' + o.aData[0] + '"><_img src="link_image" title="Edit"/></a>';                    
     },
     "aTargets": [6]                    
}]
```

To the first button I could do, but I need to create two more, aTARGETS 7 and 8, how do I create multiple functions like this.